# Odoo9 - How to access the DOM of a formview from javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, odoo, odoo-9

I Want to change few field colors dynamically.

I couldn't do that directly like the tree view , to do the same on the form view we should use JavaScript (correct me if i'm wrong) , i'm trying a solution ,but i have a problem i don't know how to access to the DOM of a form-view ,can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [web](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/9.0) repo for examples. For the tree view search for "color" there. Here are a couple:

- https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/9.0/web_context_in_colors
- https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/9.0/web_tree_dynamic_colored_field

The approach is the same: you override/extend the class of the widget via JS, like [here](https://github.com/OCA/web/blob/9.0/web_tree_dynamic_colored_field/static/src/js/web_tree_dynamic_colored_field.js#L55), **no matter if is a list/tree view or a form view**.

This one for instance [acts on form view](https://github.com/OCA/web/blob/9.0/web_access_rule_buttons/static/src/js/web_access_rule_buttons.js). As you see, is plenty of examples. Still, you should provide more info on what you are trying to achieve.

Last but not least, read [the official docs about javascript](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/javascript.html) and check stack overflow for [existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606168/odoo-9-how-to-override-form-widgets).

---