# How to inherit or override js file in odoo?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, odoo-10

I want to change a function in `js` file. How to do it? Is there any ways to override the function?

`addons/web/static/src/js/views/form_common.js`,

i want to change the `function-get_search_result: function(search_val){}`

```
dataset.name_search(search_val, self.build_domain(), 'ilike', 160).done(function(_data) {self._search_create_popup("search", _data);}
```

need to change the value `160` to something else

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just inherit base file in your custom module and then override function. You get reference from web modules only how to inherit file. You can get reference from form_relation_widget.js After that call your function without super. Now it is overridden.

Comment: I have some issues in POS, could you please help? my questions are here on StackOverflow: `1.`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60280924/how-to-auto-login-in-odoos-web-module-for-res-user-not-for-res-partner, `2.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60349247/how-do-i-hide-navbar-and-root-menu-at-sidebar-from-odoos-web-backend-module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good answer/example on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35350507/3330552), which gives a pretty good overview. That example is actually a bit more in depth than necessary for a global JavaScript change.

If you identify the function you want to override, then it's mostly just a matter of mirroring core and making the override(s) you want. Here's an example overview of how to change the `name_search` JavaScript behavior:

#### your_module/**manifest**.py

```
...
'data': [
    ...
    'views/assets.xml',
    ...
],
...
```

#### your_module/views/assets.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="custom assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/your_module/static/src/js/custom.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

#### your_module/static/src/js/custom.js

```
odoo.define('your_module.custom_feature', function(require) {
"use strict";

Class = require('web.Class');
mixins = require('web.mixins');

var DataSet = Class.extend(mixins.PropertiesMixin, {
    name_search: function (name, domain, operator, limit) {
        /* Custom code to override/extend core */
    },
});

return {
    DataSet: DataSet,
};

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like they did in `google_calendar`:

```
odoo.define('youmodule.yourmodule', function (require) {
   "use strict";
   var CompletionFieldMixin = require('web.CompletionFieldMixin');

   var _t = core._t;
   var QWeb = core.qweb;

   CompletionFieldMixin.include({
       // You need to redefine the function here
});
```