# How to call a custom JS file in Odoo 8?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8

I have a model called **student**. I also have *form view*, *tree view* for the student model. What I want to do is call my custom javascript file only when the form view of the **student** model is loaded. Is it possible? How to achieve this? Thanks.

What I tried is .....

```
openerp.student= function (instance) {

instance.web.FormView.include({

    load_form: function(data) {
        var self = this;
        if (data.model === "student") {
            altert('HELLO');
            console.log('BLAH BLAH');
        }
        return this._super(data);
    },

});
};
```

Comment: You need to add it in a folder name static and inside it another folder call it src odoo will get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add a new view mode by extending `FormFiew` as Odoo did with [account_move_line_quickadd](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account/static/src/js/account_move_line_quickadd.js#L8).

```
openerp.your_module_name = function (instance) {
    var _t = instance.web._t,
    _lt = instance.web._lt;
    var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

    instance.web.your_module_name = instance.web.your_module_name || {};

    instance.web.views.add('student_form', 'instance.web.StudentFormView');

    instance.web.StudentFormView = instance.web.FormView.extend({

        load_form: function(data) {
            var self = this;
            // Add your custom code here
            return this._super(data);
        },
    });
};
```

You just need to add the new mode to window action.

```
<record id="student_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">student.action</field>
        <field name="res_model">student</field>
        <field name="view_mode">student_form,tree</field>
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But what if I don't want a new view? I just want to extend my form view.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `load_form` method of `FormView`.

```
openerp.module_name= function (instance) {

    instance.web.FormView.include({

        load_form: function(data) {
            var self = this;
            if (data.model === "student") {
                // Your custom code
            }
            return this._super(data);
        },

    });
};
```

To add the above code check this link [inherit-or-override-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186406/how-to-inherit-or-override-js-file-in-odoo)

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work though I did the same way as you said.

Comment: Your code should work unless the model is not `student`.

Comment: Can you please show the declaration of the `student` model?

Comment: `from openerp.osv import osv, fields

class student(osv.osv):

    _name = 'student'
    _description = 'Student'

    _columns = {

        'name' : fields.char('Name'),
        'age' : fields.integer('Age'),

    }
student()`

Comment: The code should work, unless your javascript file is not loaded