# How do I hide navbar and root-menu at sidebar from Odoo's web-backend module?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

I am working on `POS Point of sales module,` I am opening an Iframe in mobile device to show POS screen but I wanted to hide navbar and sidebar of root-menu items, so normal users can use only POS dashboard.

I have installed POS_Mobile snippet to make it responsive on mobile phones and there I tried writting JS code to hide it.

but it's opening only when I start any POS-session by clicking on `resume`.

I tried as:

In file `pos_mobile_template.xml`, adding JQuery as:

```
 if ($(window).width() < 768) {

            //$("nav.o_main_navbar").hide();

    }else{

       // $("nav.o_main_navbar").show();

    }
```

but it didn't work as this template is not loaded on POS-dashboard.

[image: screenshot]

This is how I am trying to make it, (now I did it by deleting navbar, by inspecting elements, which is same I wanted to do but don't know where to inherit and write, without affecting other functionality).

[image: final output I wanted]

This is how actually it is:

[image: current screen]

also, I tried passing param `hide_header=true`, but that works only for frontend modules not `web-backend` module.

How can I inherit base POS module and add my JS code to hide navbar, sidebar in mobile devices only when I open for POS-menu?

Comment: do you want to hide it for mobile views for all users?

Comment: @TanzilKhan , I want to hide for mobile users, because that POS dashboard will be opened in an iframe in app.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS file, for example: **your_module/static/src/css/assets_common.css**

In the CSS file write following:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .o_main_navbar {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

**this media query is just an example, use yours as you need*

Then create an XML file, for example: **your_module/views/assets.xml**

In there link the CSS file:

```
    <template id="assets_common" inherit_id="web.assets_common">
        <xpath expr="//link[last()]" position="after">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/your_module/static/src/css/assets_common.css"/>
        </xpath>
    </template>
```

In the **manifest** file add 'web' as depends.

Now update app list and upgrade. Then you should see the CSS is taking effect for mobile view.

Comment: Thanks @Tanzil, I will try this and update you here.

Comment: do I have to add new module in additional_addons or I can directly use default-current module and add css in any file? but can I add any file in `manifest` as depends on `web`, instead of new-module?

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh you should create new module